# what to do when I am banned from superuser, and I have few questions to ask

Tags: discussion, post-ban

without a notification I got negative votes and got banned for the last question I asked in superuser, I deleted it, but then I noticed it's not the solution, I have few answers to correct ,and my profession is not in a level to answer other questions

I think it's not a good idea to start answering other questions when you have a new one, it's like a torture, you go answering other questions, you get negative again, you go correct them ,someone else arrives give a negative vote for his taste, you see how stupid it gets ?

Comment: Answering questions won't return your ability to ask your own questions.  Your privilege to ask questions and answer questions are separate.  Instead of deleting questions that were not well received you should edit them, so they are on topic, if they cannot be improved upon only then should they be deleted.

Answer (score 9):

It's not 'the last question' – 6 of 10 of your questions were deleted. Sometimes we notice and manually send a message, there are question ban warnings, and one rarely gets *suddenly* banned from asking questions.

If we *must*, let's look at why you got question banned – not only are 6 questions deleted, some are *self* deleted, and this sort of thing is what leads to question bans. Furthermore – in some cases, someone asked for further information, which you could have edited in instead of deleting.

I'd also add that these bans are automatic – there is nothing a mod can do.

I'd add that for most people this system works well, and we can't really change it because someone doesn't *get it*.

And well, here's part of the issue. We can't really monitor every user, and make them ask better questions. Lots of folks complain, but low quality questions aren't as helpful to other users who may have the same issues.

By making users post answers and try to do *quality* edits, we try to help them better understand how questions should be. It's not stupid; it’s a reasonable compromise.

On the poster's request, here's a list of his deleted questions, and the reasons for them. I'm not going to be explaining the specifics of what the roomba is, since the automatic deletion system is well documented.

[I tried to increase windows boot up speed but contrary happend [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/998292/i-tried-to-increase-windows-boot-up-speed-but-contrary-happend)
Manual close, roombaed.

[Questions about a CPU configuration [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/998638/questions-about-a-cpu-configuration)
Mod close, roombaed.

[Driver Pack gets error while updating windows drivers](https://superuser.com/questions/1023032/driver-pack-gets-error-while-updating-windows-drivers)
Self deletion – David's comment would have salvaged the question significantly.

[windows 10 clock confuses when I set demonstrating two zones [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/1024426/windows-10-clock-confuses-when-i-set-demonstrating-two-zones)
Roombaed, manually closed. Might be a candidate for improvement.

[What does the %% signs in batch file refer to and where are they read from [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/1036444/what-does-the-signs-in-batch-file-refer-to-and-where-are-they-read-from)
3 questions in one. Title and question don't quite seem to match. Roombaed.

[how is it possible to create a macro recorder for any software that you are working with [closed]](https://superuser.com/questions/1043475/how-is-it-possible-to-create-a-macro-recorder-for-any-software-that-you-are-work)
Title seems fixable, question is hard to read. Roombaed and might work with a rewrite.

And since I went into trouble to try to work out which questions are salvageable..

Let’s talk about improving your question-asking skills. The [help] links to ESR's 'How to ask a question the smart way'. Works wonders if you need to polish up your question asking skills. [These checklists are *glorious*](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#formats) and even I, while being a near native English speaker, and someone who has asked some well-received questions here refers to often.

I tend to break most of my questions down into 3 parts.

1. What do I have?
2. What am I trying to do?
3. What is my desired result?

Let me grab a *really* short real-world question to demonstrate.

> I'm using gntp-send to send messages to a growl for windows instance.
>   It hasn't been maintained a while so there doesn't seem to be support
>   for windows 10 style notifications. How would I get growl to work with
>   the new style notifications?

Just three lines. In a bigger, longer questions I would split this into 3 paragraphs. Breaking up your questions this way would help readability a lot.

First part describes my environment and the tools. In some cases I might choose to add versions and OSes but these things work.

Second part describes my problem – I want GFW to give Windows 10 style notifications.

Third part describes the outcome I want.

Let’s put these principles to work for one of *your* questions.

> I got driver pack version 15.12 to update automatically the drivers ,
>   but on most of the drivers , when driver pack is running , I get a
>   warning message that windows might not function properly , like the
>   driver can not stop and get updated, if so, how could I update my
>   drivers ??
>
> I use windows 10 home edition

1. Your environment. "Driver Pack" is a generic sounding name. Adding a link would have helped. I would rephrase this as "I'm running Driver Pack version 15.12 on Windows 10 Home.
2. Your problem

   > When driver pack is running , I get a
   >   warning message that windows might not function properly , like the
   >   driver can not stop and get updated

   ***Add a screenshot.*** Screenshots make sure the error message is *exactly* what is said and adds significantly to the accuracy of the question.
3. What you want

   > How do I use driverpack 15.12 to update my drivers?

   The answer might be "you can't, use the official drivers," but this format makes it easier to read.

Comment: So self deleting a question has a negative effect on your account? Does the same apply to self-deleted answers?

Comment: The system sees no difference between a self-deletion, a community/mod deletion or a roomba deletion as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Burgi - Any form of removal of a question or answer will count against or for a user's ability to submit new content , all content once submitted( questions or answers ), will forever be used to calculate your ability to ask a question or answer a question respectfully.  In other words a user should make sure whatever they submit is the highest quality before they hit the "Post your Answer" or "Post your Question" button.

Comment: Thank you very much all, but now I can't find my deleted questions, and I don't know how to improve my questions,  I do really need to remove my bann

Comment: They might have been permanently deleted (but still factored into the equation), if that is the case, you can only improve your questions that were not deleted.  You will have to hope your not so far down the rabbit hole you can't crawl out of it.  If you are that far down, nothing you can do about it, the only way to get your ability to post questions returned is to improve the score of all your questions to the point its returned.  *There isn't an override, you were warned of the quality of your questions, before this happened*  You might not have seen the warning but it was there.

Comment: "I can't find my deleted questions" While its a bit of work for me, I can help you with that. "I don't know how to improve my questions" I can't help you with that, really. And well, if you can't improve old questions, how can you ask *quality* questions in future?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, this checklist http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#formats is excellent. Can I use it when I want to show people how to post a good question?

Comment: @Prasanna - That is a horrible checklist.

Comment: What is the negative vote here then

Comment: @Farzad64 - A vote on a meta website means we either agree or disagree with you.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm curious to how its terrible, considering I recommended it.

Comment: Hi All , I have tried to correct some of my deleted answers, I hope I get rid of the useless negative votes

Comment: Anyone following?

Comment: I have been trying to update the questions,  I just got the contrary results

Comment: @Farzad64 You need to undelete your corrected deleted answers where possible otherwise nobody can see them (other than moderators).

Comment: @Farzad64 Your "update" to [Questions about a CPU configuration](http://superuser.com/q/998638) makes not a lot of sense and certainly doesn't make your question any clearer.

Comment: @Farzad64 Your edit to [Driver Pack gets error while updating windows drivers](http://superuser.com/q/1023032) does not provide the information asked for. "Please edit your question to include what driver pack you downloaded and where you download it from. We also need to know what make/model your device is and what version of Windows you are using. And what is the full error message?". The only thing you added was the version. Where is the rest of it?

Comment: @Farzad64 - Calling a person's votes "useless" isn't very nice.  the down votes you have been receiving are well justified based on the quality of your questions has been rubbish ( this is a true statement based on the fact, you received such low community acceptance of your questions, you don't have he ability to ask new questions ).  *But what do i know, I just dish out, useless votes.*

Comment: @Prasanna that entire article is a good article, though the much shorter https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask published here on SE is probably easier to get through for most people. I think the thing Ramhound may be focusing on is that you linked specifically to the Format section which is specifically about sending questions to mailing lists and isn't really applicable to SE sites. The whole page: Good. The Format section: not applicable here.